# Poisson Distribution Generation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have tried to generate a Poisson distribution in VHDL. I have not come up with the expected result. Pls help me to find some specific packages for random number generation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Open Source VHDL Verification Methodology (OS-VVM)](http://osvvm.org/), where 4th bullet says "supports favor_small, favor_big, Gaussian and Poisson distribution".

An alternative is [Verification Guild](http://verificationguild.com/) where there is a [package here](http://verificationguild.com/dload/utils/vhdl/random1.vhd).